Processing process and UniqueConstraint Django
I did model with constraints:
class DiscountSchema(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "DiscountSchema"
        constraints = [
            constraints.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=(
                    "level",
                    "level_value",
                    "discount_rate",
                    "background_col",
                    "foreground_col",
                    "loyalty_card",
                ),
                violation_error_message="UNIQUEERROR",
                name="Uniqueschema",
            )
        ]


How can I process this constraints when I create instance in serializer?
Now I have:
        try:
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            return serializer.save()
        except IntegrityError as e:
            if "Uniqueschema" in e.args[0]:
                pass
            else:
                raise e

Is there better way?

Since [tag:Django-4.0], normally the model has a .full_clean() that checks the unique constraints, and thus it shouldd never save the items.

Assuming you're using a CreateView of some kind (ListCreateView, or ModelViewSet etc), you could override the create method which might feel a bit cleaner?
class DiscountSchema(ListCreateView):
    ...

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except IntegrityError:
            return Response(status=400)

If you have unique constraints on a number of models, you could implement a custom exception handler for DRF so you don't have to put this logic in every view.
You register your handler with DRF in your settings:
REST_FRAMEWORK = {'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'api.handlers.custom_exception_handler'}

(replace the value with wherever you put your handler)
Then define something like this for your handler:

from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import IntegrityError
from rest_framework.views import Response, exception_handler
from rest_framework import status


def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)
    if isinstance(exc, IntegrityError) and not response:
        response = Response(
            {'message': '<your error message here>'},
            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
        )
    return response

Just remember, if you decide to use your own custom exception handler, if you call serializer.is_valid() manually anywhere in your code (i.e. if you've overridden any DRF viewsets for example and called serializer.is_valid()), you'll need to add raises_exception to your is_valid() call like this
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True). As for your custom exception handler to run, it needs an exception to be raised.
Hope this helps!
